# Doxygen Documentation for Google Tests

Tags: c++, unit-testing, documentation, doxygen, googletest

Is it possible to create doxygen based documentation for Google Tests as well? I followed this link to create documentation for my C++ code, which consists of a bunch of classes.

https://flcwiki.desy.de/How%20to%20document%20your%20code%20using%20doxygen

I used the default config file and put all file paths in the `INPUT =` section.

This method works well and creates documentation for my class headers and .cpp files but nothing happens with my `test.cpp` file which looks like this:

```
/**
* Tests the setter for Player Id.
*/

TEST(playerTest, setPIdTest) {

    Player p;
    p.setPId(2);
    EXPECT_EQ(2, p.getPId());
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
    return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

No documentation gets generated for the Google Tests. Am I making a mistake or doxygen simply doesn't work in this case?

Comment: What is the extension of the test file? Which doxygen version are you using? What are the setings in your doxygen configuration file, different from the default configuration file?

Comment: @albert it's tests.cpp. I used the default file ```doxygen -g <config_file>``` and just changed the ```INPUT``` & ```OUTPUT``` fields mainly. Doxygen version is 1.8.13.

Comment: Maybe it helps when you set in `test.cpp` / `tests.cpp` as first line `/// \file`.

Comment: Yup that worked! @albert Is there an explanation to it?

Comment: Doxygen is sometimes quite picky especially when there is no corresponding `.h` file with a `.cpp` file.